# Is it possible to navigate from a composable screen to a Fragment in Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

I just started working at a new company and their code base is a mix of XML and Jetpack compose. I need to implement navigation from a main screen to a settings screen but one screen is 100% compose while the other is a composable function hosted by a fragment which also has some compose code in the fragment class itself.

This is the whole setup:

An activity calls a composable function in its `onCreate()`

This composable function is said main screen which has its own Nav graph

From this composable, I need to navigate to a fragment that holds another nav graph and compose screen

The way I see it, there is no way to do this other than to rewrite the fragment as a composable screen since you cant use compose navigation to navigate to fragments / activities as far as I know.

Any pointers would be appreciated

Comment: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation has a section on Interoperability and how to navigate from compose to fragments. Can you expand your question to address why this isn't working for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compose Nav graph will **only support screens which are composable** functions. We can't use fragments/activities with Nav graph to navigate.

Instead of using navgraph, **pass a lambda function to the parameter of the initial composable** function for navigation.

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            // Pass a lambda function here
            MainNavGraph(onNavigate = {
                // Navigate to the activity/fragment from here
            })
        }
    }
    
    @Composable
    fun MainNavGraph(onNavigate: () -> Unit) {
       
        // Invoke lambda as per the logic
        onNavigate.invoke()
    }

}
```